# FreeBSD's sendmail

Tags: freebsd, sendmail

```
-bash-3.2# hostname 
name.foo.bar.domain.tld
-bash-3.2#
```

whenever I send an email it leaves as userid@name.foo.bar.domain.tld, I need to have sendmail change it to userid@domain.tld

how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default installed FreeBSD sendmail you should not be editing the .cf files directly.  They are generated from .mc files in the /etc/mail directory.

There is a Makefile in /etc/mail that will generate the .cf from the .mc files

Add the following line to the .mc files to set the default domain:

```
define(`confDOMAIN_NAME',`domain.tld')
```

If you really want to edit the .cf file directly, I believe the correct line is:

```
Djdomain.tld
```

(don't include the $w.)

Update: How to use make to regenerate your .cf

```
cd /etc/mail
make #the first time you do this it will copy freebsd.mc and freebsd.submit.mc to ${HOSTNAME}.mc and ${HOSTNAME}.submit.mc then generate the .cf files
make install   # will copy ${HOSTNAME}.cf and ${HOSTNAME}.submit.cf to sendmail.cf and sendmail.submit.cf
make restart  # will restart your sendmail processes
```

you must be root.

Comment: after I make change to freebsd.mc what do I need to to in order to convert that .mc to .cf?

Comment: make -C /etc/mail ?

Comment: updated the answers with make usage

Comment: that worked, thank you very much
although just FYI for others you need to make a change to ${HOSTNAME}submit.mc not ${HOSTNAME}.mc

Answer (score 1):

```
# my official domain name
# ... define this only if sendmail cannot automatically determine your domain
#Dj$w.Foo.COM
```

should be in /etc/mail/sendmail.cf

Comment: so I should have
Dj$w.domain.tld ?

Comment: yes, something like that

Comment: i tried in both sendmail.cf and submit.cf, not working for me...

Comment: did you restart sendmail after modifying .cf ?

Comment: of course /etc/rc.d/sendmail restart